# Unable to locate json data file while making http get request in angular cli project

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-cli

Repo: https://github.com/avalokkumar/gametrackers

I'm unable to make http request to src/games-data.json from app/games/shared/GamesService as it is not able to locate the file path correctly.
Please suggest any solution.
Thanks.

Comment: It's under `src/data/games-data.json` rather than `src/games-data.json`

Comment: thanks!
My typo mistake. Working fine now.

Comment: You should post this as an answer and accept it so others can see that 
your problem was solved, especially if you solved it yourself :)

Comment: sure! Will do that.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the path **src/games-data.json** to **src/data/games-data.json** in app/games/shared/GamesService did the work.

Comment: please accept this answer if it fixes your issue as you describe :)